# Printing multiple characters from a string

Tags: java

If I have a string "SSSAAADDDCCC" how would I print just "SADC". Can it be done using SubString or would I have to use charAt()?

Answer (score 1):

There is a simple way to do this - however since I don't see any code and I do not see any effort on your part I will not just give you the answer. Below is some psudo code you can work off to try to find the right answer. Good Luck!

```
currentChar = myString.charAt(0);
i = 0;
print current character //as per comments, cover the base case
while(string has more characters)
    if current character != next character
       print next character
    i++
```

Comment: I like your no-code approach but there is one problem with "print next character". How will this solution work for string like `abc` because it looks like only `b` and `c` will be printed.

Comment: Ah - well stated. I'll update with that in mind.

Answer (score 0):

Use regular expression to replace all *repeating* characters with a single character:

```
"SSSAAADDDCCC".replaceAll("(.)\\1+", "$1")   // returns "SADC"
```

`(.)` matches and *captures* a character.
`\\1+` matches one or more instances of the captured character.
`$1` replaces the entire matched value with the captured character.

Non-repeating characters are not matched, and are therefore left alone.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't like the charAt method you could use substrings like this:

```
int j=0;
String in="sssdddaaaccc";
String out="";
for(int i=0;i<4;i++)
{
    out=out+in.subString(j,j+1);
    for(j=j; j<3;j++);
}
System.out.println(out);
```